# How to locate and remove a node from a LinkedList that has only one element, its head?

Tags: java

How can I locate and remove a node from a `LinkedList` that has only one element, its **head**? It does not have any tail, current, header, trailer and counter.

I also want to

- throw a `NullPointerException` if the list is empty
- return **true** if the supplied value is found and removed
- return **false** if the supplied value is not found

```
Public class SLList
{

    Private class Node
    {
        Private int info;
        Private Node next;
        Private Node (int value, Node ptr)
        {
            Info = value;
            Next = ptr;
        }
    }

    Protected Node head = null;

    Public Boolean remove (int value) throws NullPointerException
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: `Private` or `private`?

Comment: it was my exam question, it certainly has answer

Comment: better to return status code for many return states, like success, failure, no nodes in tree etc instead of throwing NPE.

Answer (score 1):

if only head exists it means that head.next is null, check it inside the remove() :

```
    if (head != null){
        if (head.next == null){
            // only head exists - remove it
            head = null;
        }
        else {
            // remove other nodes normally
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you, but as it mentioned in the question, it should not have any counter!!!